# ActiveSupport::Concern Callback - undefined method for NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I am trying to set up a utility callback that can be used for multiple models in my Rails app using `ActiveSupport::Concern`. I have the following `Postable` module:

`/app/models/concerns/postable.rb`

```
module Concerns::Postable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do |base|
        base.after_save :correct_article_url, if: Proc.new { |post| post.article_url.present? }
    end

    def correct_article_url
        # do something with the url
    end
end
```

Here is my `Post` model:

`/app/models/post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::Postable
end
```

When I create a new instance of `Post` and call `post.save`, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `correct_article_url' for #<Post:0x007fdb58a35b98>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It should work. What rails/ruby version are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2.5 / ruby 2.3

Comment: okay lemme re generate it with Rails 4.2.5 & Ruby 2.3.0 

In the mean time. is there any chance that your are testing it with Rails Console ? You need to reload the environment if added `correct_article_url` later

Comment: I'm not testing it with the console.

Comment: It's working fine with rails 4.2.5 & Ruby 2.3.0

There is not anything wrong with this code. Just try to restart your server. May be it fixes. (although it should auto load in dev environment)

Comment: There must be something wrong or it would work. I've already tried all the obvious things like restarting my server and checking for typos.

Comment: Can you paste the complete error log here ?

Comment: Here is the complete log output: https://gist.github.com/danielbonnell/01bc503620b82d29943ec6cd313c9ff9

Comment: Tried re-creating this and it works fine for me in Rails console. As a first step, could you try testing this within Rails console to see if you get the same error message? If it works in console, could you then provide the relevant source for `social_media_posts_controller.rb`?

Comment: You log is saying `undefined method correct_article_url` for `nil:NilClass:` , So there is some gotcha in your code. Can you provide a gist for your `post.rb` and `social_media_posts_controller.rb`

Comment: Indeed that appears to be the case. When I asked this question I tried to simplify the code rather than paste all 150+ lines. I cut out a bunch of very similar callbacks. One of those other callbacks was the real culprit. It was calling the method on the parent object of `post`. Sorry for the confusion. I guess that's what I get for trying to boil it down too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve it(also check the spelling of your method names)

```
module Concerns::Postable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        after_save :correct_article_url, if: Proc.new { |post| post.article_url.present? }
    end

    def correct_article_url
        # do something with the url
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a namespace? just remove the namespaces both from module and inclusion and it will work

```
 module Postable
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do |base|
      base.after_save :correct_article_url, if: Proc.new { |post| post.article_url.present? }
 end

 def correct_article_url
     # do something with the url
 end
end
```

Comment: That had no effect.